# Creating a custom widget compatible with GWT Editor-Driver Framework

Tags: java, gwt

I have an Entity  on server side with a field List< String > xyz. So I want to write an Editor for this entity but also I want to use a custom widget for this particular field. As I am not fully sure about the working of Editor-Driver framework and I am still in learning process. So how is that done? Should I use CompositeEditor interface or IsEditor interface or just Editor interface is enough for it.

If possible please also explain the definition of CompositeEditor,EditorDelegate,IsEditor interfaces and anything else you know about the working of Editor-Driver Framework except what is already not explained on http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/Editors .

Comment: Can't say much more than reading both the official [doc](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors) and the always clear broyer's [article](http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-editors). I'd suggest you to start with this [sample](https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/780560) which let you understand the basics (but does not use list editors, though), and then move to the official GWT DynaTable sample (a bit more complex, but it should include your use case).

Answer (score 0):

Above can be achieved by implementing LeafValueEditor in a Composite Widget. Then a ListEditor can be used to maintain the list of those Widgets.

Example: https://sites.google.com/site/mygwtexamples/home/ui/listeditor

And as far as I have understood IsEditor interface is implemented when we need to incorporate working of those Editors which do not follow Editor Contract directly. May be it means that they do not have subeditors. And clearly a LeafValueEditor and ListEditor doesn't have subeditors to descend into.